# How to get the result of table contains numeric and strings using where condition in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table like below

[image]

When I select item_no>'1623G' from above table

I want to print the result below

```
1623H | 1623I | 1666 | 1674 | 1912 | 1952 | 1953
```

I am trying below command

```
select * from t where substring(item_no,'([0-9]+)') :: int  > 1623G
```

But it's not giving result
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the regexp way:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=365e8a130b8dade68bd0ce9a6482fe36)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        item_no,
        regexp_replace(item_no, '\D', '', 'g')::int AS digit,
        regexp_replace(item_no, '\d', '', 'g') AS nondigit,
        regexp_replace('200a', '\D', '', 'g')::int AS compare_digit,
        regexp_replace('200a', '\d', '', 'g') AS compare_nondigit
    FROM t
)
SELECT
    item_no
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    (digit > compare_digit) OR (digit = compare_digit AND nondigit > compare_nondigit)
```

Splitting both values (the row value and the comparing one) into its both parts (digits and non-digits) and compare each part separately.

I am curious if there is better solution.

Comment: I have tried this by passing '0005' but it is returning rows but it should not.

Comment: @Vivek Why not? It's completely ok. 0005 == 5 and 20, 200, 2000 are greater

Comment: Perfect, thats mine misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CONVERT_TO** as:

```
testdb1=# CREATE TABLE t (item_no varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE
testdb1=# INSERT INTO t VALUES('2'),('20'),('200'),('200a'),('200b'),('200c'),('2000');
INSERT 0 7
testdb1=# SELECT * FROM t;
 item_no 
---------
 2
 20
 200
 200a
 200b
 200c
 2000
(7 rows)

testdb1=# select * from t where substring(convert_to(item_no,'SQL_ASCII')::text,3)::int > substring(convert_to('2a','SQL_ASCII')::text,3)::int;
 item_no 
---------
 200
 200a
 200b
 200c
 2000
(5 rows)

testdb1=# select * from t where substring(convert_to(item_no,'SQL_ASCII')::text,3)::int > substring(convert_to('150','SQL_ASCII')::text,3)::int;
 item_no 
---------
 200
 200a
 200b
 200c
 2000
(5 rows)
```

Comment: If one record has value as "3" and another as "4" then it is returning two more records as "3" and "4" with "2h" and "2d" in my case. Am using PG 11.4, not sure in 9.5.

Comment: @Vivek I llike your idea, but it really does not work... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0cc094e76634b35684380c394a5c027f

Comment: @vivek tried in version 11.4 its giving all values except 1623G

Comment: @S-Man Thanks for your notice, I have updated the answer now it will handle the actual string to ascii conversion and then conditional filter

Comment: @Vivek: Still not working. Try 200a instead 2a. Then you would miss 2000 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=746b54b19050f2888793792c2c9459e9

Comment: @Vivek The problem is that in ASCII "0" is smaller than "a". So 200_0_ is smaller than 200_a_